# No "Generate an app-specific password" section in my Apple ID

Tags: apple-id

I can't reproduce what is described in [this Cnet article](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-create-app-specific-passwords-for-icloud/).

Here is my screenshot.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need activate "Two-Step Verification" in order to "generate an app specific password" as shown in http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-create-app-specific-passwords-for-icloud/

> For those unfamiliar, app-specific passwords are used when an app or service you're attempting to sign into doesn't support two-step verification. Instead of forcing you to enter your account password, you create a single-use app-specific password, eliminating any potential for your account to be compromised.

And as shown in your screenshot "Two-Step Verification" is not enabled...

Comment: Is it the only way to activate it? My apps hadn't needed it for a long time, why do they need that now?

Comment: "...why do they need that now?" because it is a new feature.